# Can't catch specific exception using ExecutorService and Callables?

Tags: java, exception, executorservice, callable

The general advice for catching exceptions is that it's better to be specific, instead of just catching exceptions from the broadest class: java.lang.Exception.

But it seems like the only exception from callable is ExecutionException.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class ThreadTest {

    private final static ArrayList<Callable<Boolean>> mCallables = new ArrayList<>();
    private final static ExecutorService mExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        testMethod();
    }

    static void testMethod() throws Exception {

        mCallables.clear();

        for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
            mCallables.add(new Callable<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                    //if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    //    throw new InterruptedException("Interruption");
                    //}
                    System.out.println("New call");

                    double d = Double.parseDouble("a");

                    return true;
                } //end call method

            }); //end callable anonymous class
        }
        try {
            List<Future<Boolean>> f= mExecutor.invokeAll(mCallables);
            f.get(1).get();
            f.get(2).get();
            f.get(3).get();
            f.get(0).get();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Number Format exception");
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            String s = e.toString();
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println("Execution exception");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Some other exception");
        }

        mExecutor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

In the above code, I would like to catch NumberFormatException, but I can't seem to catch anything except ExecutionException.

If there are multiple different exceptions thrown from the call method, how would someone catch the different exceptions separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will always get an `ExecutionException`. The root exception will be set as the cause. Call `getCause()` on the `ExecutionException` instance to get to the actual exception that was thrown in the `Callable`.